# 'they have' or 'the ones have'?

Tags: grammar

I have two sentences.

> **The cars** underwent a rapid change from the application of mechanical technology to digital, that currently takes advantage of
>   artificial intelligence. Currently, **they have** become large.

Can I say: Currently, **the ones** have become large?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't really say that.

"The ones" would be used in a situation where you are identifying some subset:

> - The ones in the corner
> - the ones with a sign on the windshield
> - the ones that have autopilot
> - the red ones

You need to supply some distinguishing feature that allows us to identify *which* "ones" you are talking about; if you are talking about all of them, the all-inclusive "they" is appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

It is grammatically correct to say, "The ones have ..." But in this case, it would result in an unclear sentence. Which ones? "They" has a clear antecedent: "the cars". But "the ones" introduces a new subject and never makes clear what it is referring to. In this case, do you mean "the cars that underwent a rapid change"? The ones that didn't undergo the change? Some subset of the ones that changed? Etc.